# RAID0 disk recovery?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, hardware-rec, raid-0

I've not lost a RAID0 setup but since both drives are used as one, is there anyway possible to even access data on just one drive via a sata cable or will you need both drives in a RAID0 setup to be able to access files?

Example:
Are files say file.ext kept on one drive to be accessed or would it spread among both? I'm guessing it would possible be spread among both since both drives are acting as one and it would be a random chance the file being spread among both drives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a Raid 0 array is set up it sets what is called a strip size, can be 32,64,128 kb etc. Most are set to 64 kB by default.

Files are split up in chunks, each chunk having the size of the strip size. Half of the chunks are saved in each drive. So, your file is spread out in both drives. There is no parity information stored so the file cannot be reconstructed without the other pieces.

So you cannot recover much from one drive (it'll have just half of the file), and yes you need the same raid controller and firmware version to recover data from the drives, so if the raid controller fails, you better have an exact match backup controller or you will have to pay for professional recovery which is astronomical for raid 0.

Never store critical data on a Raid 0 array unless you have regular backups to another storage device.

[Related Question](https://superuser.com/questions/60544/can-someone-explain-raid-0-in-plain-english)

Comment: Thats it ^.  In testing I have pulled some files off a 1/2 the team , the files were the ones that fit on only one drive item because they were smaller than the stripe size, other than that the drive might just as well be thrown in the trash without its team, the data all looked like it was in some unknown anchient language  :-)   Backing up raid0 to a normal big disk works good, and its reasonably fast too, having speed on one side, and seperate disk on the other.  So back-it-up.  I also let chkdsk do its thing to a 1/2 drive , and it made a lot of changes, which effected the team reassembled